# resolv.conf on host overwritten every time a Docker container is started or stopped

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Every time I start or stop any Docker container, the `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` file on the host (Ubuntu 19.04) gets overwritten with:

```
# Generated by dhcpcd from enp30s0.dhcp
# /etc/resolv.conf.head can replace this line
nameserver 127.0.0.1
# /etc/resolv.conf.tail can replace this line
```

As a result, after every reboot and after any time a container is started or stopped, I have to issue `netplan generate` and `netplan apply` to fix the resolv.conf file.

**How do I get docker to stop jacking up the host's resolv.conf file?**

My **netplan** looks like this:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp30s0:
            addresses:
            - 10.0.10.20/24
            dhcp4: no
            gateway4: 10.0.10.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 10.0.10.1
    version: 2
```

When I run `systemd-resolve --status`:

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 10.0.10.1
```

These are the various **docker containers** I have:

```
docker network create -d macvlan --subnet=10.0.10.0/24 --gateway=10.0.10.1 -o parent=enp30s0 macvlan-services-network


docker container create --name="pihole-kids" \
    --volume /opt/docker/volumes/pihole-kids/etc/pihole:/etc/pihole \
    --volume /opt/docker/volumes/pihole-kids/etc/dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d \
    --volume /opt/docker/volumes/pihole-kids/var/log/pihole.log:/var/log/pihole.log \
    --net macvlan-services-network \
    --ip 10.0.10.21 \
    --publish 53:53/tcp \
    --publish 53:53/udp \
    --publish 80:80 \
    --publish 443:443 \
    --dns=127.0.0.1 \
    --dns=10.0.10.20 \
    --add-host=restrict.youtube.com:216.239.38.120 \
    --add-host=restrictmoderate.youtube.com:216.239.38.119 \
    --add-host=forcesafesearch.google.com:216.239.38.120 \
    --add-host=strict.bing.com:204.79.197.220 \
    --add-host=safe.duckduckgo.com:34.243.144.154 \
    --env IPv6=False \
    --env ServerIP=10.0.10.21 \
    --env TZ="America/Chicago" \
    --restart=unless-stopped \
    pihole/pihole:latest



docker container create --name="pihole" \
    --volume /opt/docker/volumes/pihole/etc/pihole:/etc/pihole \
    --volume /opt/docker/volumes/pihole/etc/dnsmasq.d:/etc/dnsmasq.d \
    --volume /opt/docker/volumes/pihole/var/log/pihole.log:/var/log/pihole.log \
    --net=host \
    --env IPv6=False \
    --env ServerIP=10.0.10.20 \
    --env TZ="America/Chicago" \
    --dns=127.0.0.1 \
    --dns=10.0.10.1 \
    --restart=unless-stopped \
    pihole/pihole:latest


docker container create --name="emby-server" \
    --network="host" \
    --volume /opt/docker/volumes/emby/config:/config \
    --volume /mnt/media:/mnt/media \
    --device /dev/dri:/dev/dri \
    --runtime=nvidia \
    --publish 8096:8096 \
    --publish 8920:8920 \
    --env UID=997 \
    --env GID=997 \
    --env GIDLIST=1000 \
    --env NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all \
    --env NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=compute,utility,video \
    emby/embyserver:latest


docker container create --name="nzbhydra2" \
    --volume /opt/docker/volumes/nzbhydra2/config:/config \
    --volume /mnt/Downloads:/mnt/Downloads \
    --volume /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro \
    --publish 5076:5076 \
    --env UMASK=000 \
    --env PUID=1004 \
    --env PGID=1004 \
    binhex/arch-nzbhydra2


docker container create --name="portainer" \
    --volume /opt/docker/volumes/portainer/data:/data \
    --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    --publish 9000:9000 \
    --restart=always \
    portainer/portainer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIGURED IT OUT!

At some point, `dhcpcd` was installed on my system.  No idea why.  Before I decided to remove it, I edited the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file and replaced the `127.0.0.1` with `10.0.10.1` to see if `/etc/resolv.conf` would change.  I rebooted and it indeed changed.  I removed `dhcpcd` with `apt purge dhcpcd5`, rebooted, and now the nameservers remain  consistent with what I have in my netplan.

Hopefully this is helpful for someone else that goes through this same problem.

Comment: Thanks! If someone's actually using `dhcpcd` like me: you can use its `allowinterfaces`/`denyinterfaces` config option to prevent it from overwriting your `resolv.conf` every time new Docker network interface pops up.

Answer (score 0):

We just solved a similar issue. With every deployment of a docker container the DNS settings went back to an outdated setup.

The file `/etc/resolv.conf` pointed to `# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.`

Via `systemd-resolve --status` we found the wrong DNS settings in the network adapter,  changed it in the config files in `/etc/systemd/network` and restarted the service via `systemctl restart systemd-networkd`.

After a docker stop/start everything worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

The workaround is to bind mount resolv.conf from host.
**Make sure that 127.0.0.11 is added on hosts’s resolv.conf.**

Please make sure this workaround only works if you include 127.0.0.11 in hosts /etc/resolv.conf and copy this resolv.conf to docker compose file location.

volumes:

- ./resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Please (1) explain ***how*** to do this (i.e., what commands to use) and (2) explain *how it works.*  Link to references, if possible. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).